# Confusion about joint probability and conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

This might be trivial, but I just want to make sure I don't struggle on the basics.

I am confused about this:

"Draw one card from a standard deck of playing cards. Let’s examine the
independence of 3 events ‘the card is an ace’, ‘the card is a heart’ and ‘the card is red’.
Define the events as A = ‘ace’, H = ‘hearts’, R = ‘red’." ([Source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/01645f86d111e8fdca0be5fd46920851_MIT18_05S14_Reading3.pdf))

With $P(A) = \frac{1}{13}$, $P(H) = \frac{1}4$ and $P(R) = \frac{1}2$

I get $\frac{1}4$ for $P(H|R)$. So this basically says that $P(H)$ and $P(R)$ are independent, since H and P are independent iff $P(H|R) = P(H)$.

I know that that's not correct from the source, so now I am wondering how I can then calculate the conditional probability for dependent events and how I would know beforehand. Why is $P(H|R)$ actually $\frac{1}2$?

I feel like I am missing one bit of the puzzle or overcomplicating things, so any help is appreciated!

Best regards,
Sam!

Comment: If the card is red it is equally likely to be Hearts or Diamonds (and can't be Spades or Clubs).  More numerically, there are $26$ red cards, $13$ of which are Hearts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(H|R)$ means you already know the card is red, so your total pool is $26$ red cards. from these $26$ red cards, you want to know the probability for selecting a heart, so there are $13$ heart cards, therefore, you have

$$P(H|R)=\frac{13}{26}=\frac{1}2$$

Comment: Thanks!! 

So, when two events are dependent, the way to figure out the conditional probability is contextual? That is where my confusion is coming from, I think.

Comment: No, there is no such a law to guarantee you to do this contextual. It depends on case by case. @DerOeko